# php mail sending problem. Server not accepting html tags

Tags: php, email

I developed a simple form with mai lsending function. When the file is in our server all the functionality worked greatly. But when the files moved to our client server, in mail sending we are facing some problem. What ever HTML code i used it's simply displaying in the same format. The HTML rendering is not happening properly.. Whether problem in the server or i have to change my php code??

Comment: (This might be a serverfault question)

Comment: If u r sending mail from site at local, its will not work, Because its require internet or communication media...

Comment: I'm using online server only.. The header are set properly.. Because it was worked perfectly with my server but it's not working with the client server. Client server is dedicated server.

Comment: May be you need to use PHPMailer for sending email. You can download PHPMailer class here:
http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have setup the correct `Content-Type: HTML` on your email functionality. Please see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-2881 for more information.

Quick Info:

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Yes. I'm not added the MIME version in the header!! Is it make the problem??

Comment: @Mayilarun as long as you have the proper content-type the mail should be displayed as HTML. Did you check?